# How to pass Emgu mat to Emgu function requiring IntPtr?

Tags: vb.net, opencv, emgucv

I'm trying to use `CvInvoke.cvConvertScale` to convert a Byte-depth `mat` into an Int32-depth `mat` in preparation for summing several frames together with `CvInvoke.Add`. The convert function requires a couple of `IntPtr` parameters.

I have my first image in a Byte-depth `mat` and I've initialised an Int32-depth `mat` ready to accept the result of the convert function.

But I simply cannot figure out how to pass these `mat` as parameters to the function. `cvarrToMat` always throws `Unknown Array Type`. I've tried the following approaches:

```
'm is a mat with a Cv8U frame from a single channel video in it

Dim dataC(m.Cols * m.Rows) As Byte
Dim dataD(m.Cols * m.Rows) As Int32
Dim handleC As GCHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(dataC, GCHandleType.Pinned)
Dim handleD As GCHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(dataD, GCHandleType.Pinned)
Dim frametoaddC_Byte As New Mat(sizes:=New Integer() {m.Cols, m.Rows, m.NumberOfChannels}, type:=CvEnum.DepthType.Cv8U, data:=handleC.AddrOfPinnedObject)
Dim frametoaddD_Int32 As New Mat(sizes:=New Integer() {m.Cols, m.Rows, m.NumberOfChannels}, type:=CvEnum.DepthType.Cv32S, data:=handleD.AddrOfPinnedObject)

frametoaddC_Byte = vid.frame(i) 'Returns a mat of depth Cv8U from a video, same size as m, one channel.

'This doesn't work
CvInvoke.cvConvertScale(Marshal.GetIUnknownForObject(frametoaddC_Byte), Marshal.GetIUnknownForObject(frametoaddD_Int32), 1, 0)
'This doesn't work either
CvInvoke.cvConvertScale(handleC.AddrOfPinnedObject, handleD.AddrOfPinnedObject, 1, 0)
'And neither does this
CvInvoke.cvConvertScale(frametoaddC_Byte.Ptr, frametoaddD_Int32.Ptr, 1, 0)
'And finally, just in case, neither does this
CvInvoke.cvConvertScale(frametoaddC_Byte, frametoaddD_Int32, 1, 0)
```

(To my surprise those three `IntPtr` all have different values - quite widely different, actually. You'd think they'd all be close in memory but they're not. Anyway, never mind that.)

I've also tried replacing the Dims of the two frametoadds with this:

```
Dim frametoaddC_Byte As New Mat(m.Rows, m.Cols, CvEnum.DepthType.Cv8U, 1)
Dim frametoaddD_Int32 As New Mat(m.Rows, m.Cols, CvEnum.DepthType.Cv32S, 1)
```

That would be the usual syntax rather than bothering with GCHandle.Alloc and was actually where I started. I only tried Alloc so I had the option of using AddrOfPinnedObject in my attempts to get a valid IntPtr. But to no avail.

All my attempts lead to the same error: `Unknown Array Type` in `cvarrToMat`. Samples seem thin on the ground. I'm using Emgu 3. Any ideas?

Comment: So far I figured out this. Seems `.ptr` is the right way to get the `IntPtr` and the reason `cvarrToMat` isn't recognising my `mat` is that the mat's masked type is `42FF0000` whereas the correct MAGIC value to recognise a mat is `42420000`. I'm not sure where the value `42FF0000` is coming from and why my mat is set to it.

Comment: OK, so if anyone else is coming up against this or something similar, I **think** the problem is incompatibility between v3 data and v2 code. Instead of using `CvInvoke.cvConvertScale` I tried `mymat.ConvertTo` and it worked first time.